# CodeIgniter project .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to install a codeigniter project on a GoDaddy hosting.

I've followed the [Godaddy Installation Tips](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips) instructions from the CodeIgniter Wiki.

In config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I can access everything as such

```
http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc
```

**But**

When I have a get parameters in url

```
http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc?id=1
```

The .htaccess remove the parameter ?id=1 so

```
http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc?id=1
```

become

```
http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc
```

Comment: I cant understand why you are using querystring, you already have option of pretty urls

Comment: You can access like ```http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc/1```

Comment: querystring are in the specs of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in **.htaccess**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is

RewriteBase /


# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico|assets|forums)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.(js|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|swf|txt|xml|htc|pdf|xls|doc|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I used this in one of the project, and its working there...